# Image sharding and how to avoid multiple items in browser cache

Tags: image, sharding

To improve page render speed I am looking at implementing image sharding which serves images from the multiple subdomains. How can I ensure that the same image is retrieved from the same server?

I want to avoid a scenario like the one below where the same image is served from multiple domains:
images1.domain.com/image1.gif
images2.domain.com/image2.gif
images2.domain.com/image3.gif
images2.domain.com/image1.gif

We are running Java - is there any way to checksum/fingerprint the image-filename and based on that always assign it to the same server?

Answer (score 1):

Use an MD5 hash of the relative path to your content, then modulo this by the number of sharding domains you have. This presupposes that MD5 has a fairly even distribution across the final bit of the output (if you have two shards). My experience here was that it did. Here's a link to another question answering how to [generate MD5 hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java).

A modulo of a [checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421419/good-choice-for-a-lightweight-checksum-algorithm) might also suffice and be computationally quicker.